# Changing sh color in .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, debian, shell, debian-jessie

I'm trying to change the color of my shell which I connect to using [Putty](http://www.putty.org/).

**When I type this**

```
export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

I get exactly what I want. Everything is **green** and it's only applied for the root user so I can distinguish root from other users.

However, when I put this code *(without "export")* in `/root/.bashrc`, I get this effect when I change the current shell to bash using the command `bash`.

**Example:**

[image: example]

**How can I make my shell green, without switching to "bash" everytime I connect, i.e. how can I apply this to the default shell aswell?**

> Debian 8.3 (Jessie) is used here

Comment: `~/.bashrc` is read by Bash, what shell are you using?

Comment: `echo $SHELL` returns `/bin/bash`, so I'm obviously using bash. Why does this not work then?

Comment: Okay, I came closer now. When I create a file named `.profile` with the content `. ~/.bashrc`, I get the green shell, but the text above the first input prompt is still gray. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Yeah, `~/.bashrc` is read only by non-login shells, `~/.profile` is read by login shells. Putting it in `/etc/profile` instead should change the color of the MOTD as well.

Comment: Can you please put an answer with a description where exactly to put what and make everything (including MOTD) green, but only for root user?

Comment: No, apparently it doesn't. I can't test this reliably right now; I'll boot my Debian VM later to check directly on Debian, but in the meantime you can try Googling for "change motd color". I'll try to post an answer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `~/.bashrc` is not read by login shells, and hence it's not read by the shell you get by logging in via SSH.

As you've noticed already, `~/.profile` is read by login shells, so that's a way to set the color, but it doesn't affect the MOTD.

On Debian the MOTD is stored in `/etc/motd`; here's a command which will append the correct escape sequences at the start and at the end of the file:

```bsh
printf '\e[0;32m' | sudo perl -i -pe 'if($. == 1) { $_ = <STDIN>.$_ }' /etc/motd; printf '\e[0m' | sudo tee -a /etc/motd
```

[image: screenshot]

The `\e[0;32m` will set the color to green at the start, the `\e[0m` will reset the all the attributes at the end; this way the MOTD is changed without affecting what's printed after; if you don't want to reset the attributes at the end (affecting what's printed after the MOTD), just drop the last command:

```bsh
printf '\e[0;32m' | sudo perl -i -pe 'if($. == 1) { $_ = <STDIN>.$_ }' /etc/motd
```

Comment: `~/.profile` was very helpful. I won't set the MOTD color, though, because I want green color only for the root user. But with the profile set to green, this is the closest to what I wanted to achieve. +1